# All my links break down to origin when i launch the controller

Tags: gazebo, urdf, solidworks

so here is the image of my custom made urdf which is imported from solid works,
as you can see, all the links comes to origin when i launch the file(with the controllers),but the model remains perfect when i launch the file without controllers:

[image: img1]

if i try to turn off the physics and launch,then am getting the perfect structure:

[image: img2]

i tried changing all inertia values to a similar value of a box structure,yet am facing this error,can anyone help me out?

here is my urdf code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<robot
  name="the_dragon_mod1">

  <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
            <robotNamespace>/the_dragon_mod1</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <link name="base_link">
  </link>
  <link
    name="body_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.366280286311277" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
        
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint
    name="joint_baselink_bodylink"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 0"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="body_link" />
  </joint>

  <link
    name="link_frontal_arm">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.409869420942214" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_frontal_arm.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 0.168627450980392 0.168627450980392 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_frontal_arm.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_baselink_frontal_Arm"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.0097488 0.062233 -0.10494"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="body_link" />
    <child
      link="link_frontal_arm" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-0.5"
      upper="0.5"
      effort="0.1"
      velocity="0.01" />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran1">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_baselink_frontal_Arm">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor1">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

  <link
    name="link_front_right_cc_prop">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00656747320105913" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_front_right_cc_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_front_right_cc_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_frontal_arm_front_right_prop"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.20925 0.038441 -0.00024003"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_frontal_arm" />
    <child
      link="link_front_right_cc_prop" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran5">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_frontal_arm_front_right_prop">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor5">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
  <link
    name="link_front_left_c_prop">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0065588883521805" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_front_left_c_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_front_left_c_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_frontal_arm_front_left_prop"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.19025 0.038457 -0.000018356"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_frontal_arm" />
    <child
      link="link_front_left_c_prop" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran4">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_frontal_arm_front_left_prop">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor4">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission> 
  <link
    name="link_backward_stem">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.37381251057359" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_backward_stem.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_backward_stem.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_baselink_backward_Stem"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.00025736 0.0030338 0.10822"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="body_link" />
    <child
      link="link_backward_stem" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-0.5"
      upper="0.5"
      effort="0.1"
      velocity="0.01" />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran7">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_baselink_backward_Stem">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor7">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission> 
  <link
    name="link_backward_arm">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.409869420378759" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_backward_arm.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 0.168627450980392 0.168627450980392 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_backward_arm.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_backward_stem_backward_arm"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.0095 0.05635 0.21212"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_backward_stem" />
    <child
      link="link_backward_arm" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-0.5"
      upper="0.5"
      effort="0.1"
      velocity="0.01" />
  </joint>
  <transmission name="tran2">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_backward_stem_backward_arm">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor2">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

  <link
    name="link_back_right_c_prop">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00655886496015816" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_back_right_c_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_back_right_c_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_backward_arm_back_right_prop"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.19025 0.038457 0.00044716"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_backward_arm" />
    <child
      link="link_back_right_c_prop" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran3">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_backward_arm_back_right_prop">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor3">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
  <link
    name="link_back_left_cc_prop">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00656748727326129" />
      <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000"  ixz="0.000"  
         iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.000"
         izz="0.00001"
/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>link_back_left_cc_prop
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_back_left_cc_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://the_dragon_mod1/src/meshes4/link_back_left_cc_prop.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_backward_arm_back_left_prop"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.20925 0.038442 -0.00044713"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_backward_arm" />
    <child
      link="link_back_left_cc_prop" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>
  <transmission name="tran6">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="joint_backward_arm_back_left_prop">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor6">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>


   <gazebo reference="body_link">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="body_link">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_frontal_arm">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_frontal_arm">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_backward_arm">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_backward_arm">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_backward_stem">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_backward_stem">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>


<gazebo reference="link_back_left_cc_prop">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_back_left_cc_prop">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_back_right_c_prop">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_back_right_c_prop">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_front_right_cc_prop">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_front_right_cc_prop">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_front_left_c_prop">
        <kp>100000.0</kp>
        <kd>100000.0</kd>
        <mu1>10.0</mu1>
        <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_front_left_c_prop">
  <selfCollide>True</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="joint_baselink_frontal_Arm">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_frontal_arm_front_left_prop">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_frontal_arm_front_right_prop">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_baselink_backward_Stem">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_backward_stem_backward_arm">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_backward_arm_back_left_prop">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_backward_arm_back_right_prop">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="joint_baselink_bodylink">
  <implicitSpringDamper>True</implicitSpringDamper>
</gazebo>




</robot>
```

Comment: Please update your question to isolate this to a minimum reproducible example so that we avoid complications that may be unrelated content or multiple issues.

Comment: I know you said you double checked your inertia values, but try visualizing them in Gazebo if you can. Gazebo will render pink inertia boxes around each link if you toggle inertia display from the view menu. The inertia boxes must look like "bounding boxes" around each link to be approximately correct. If they are much smaller or much larger than the link geometry, or not oriented the same way, you will see it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The gazebo simulation is behaving as expected. You likely have two big issues you need to fix:

1. A joint driven by an Effort Controller rotates freely if it is not actively driven (this kind of joint does not hold its initial position.) So gravity will cause your object to collapse.
2. gazebo is *very* sensitive to the Inertial values. You can not just put random numbers in there; also the values change due to the link's mass. Use [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors).